# How to keep DataTables enabled when navigating between pages using pagination created by JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, pagination

I have a spring boot project that pulls data from a database, this is it only pulls 10 rows of data at a time per page(because I'm using pagination). I only want to use the DataTables library for sorting and possibly filtering by way of a string search. However, for pagination, I am using JavaScript functions for the `next` and `previous` buttons.

**Here is the problem:**
On the initial load of the program, I see the DataTables table with the data from the database and I am able to sort by each column, etc. I'm also still able to navigate between pages with my custom JavaScript code. But the moment I click on the `next` or `previous` buttons, DataTables gets removed (you'll see an example lower down).

**This is my repository.java**

```java
package com.jaiylonabbb.datatables.repository;

import com.jaiylonabbb.datatables.models.Representatives;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;

public interface RepRepository extends JpaRepository<Representatives, Integer>{
//    Representatives findByFirstnameAndLastname(String firstname, String lastname);

    List<Representatives> findByEmailStartsWith(String email);

}
```

**This is my service.java class:**

```java
package com.jaiylonabbb.datatables.service;

import com.jaiylonabbb.datatables.models.Representatives;
import com.jaiylonabbb.datatables.repository.RepRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class RepService {
    @Autowired
    private RepRepository repository;
    public Iterable<Representatives> getEntities(Integer pageNum){
        Pageable page = PageRequest.of(pageNum, 10);
        return repository.findAll(page);
    }
    public Long count(){
        return repository.count();
    }
//    public Page<Representatives> getEntities(int page, int size) {
//        PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, size);
//        return repository.findAll(pageRequest);
//    }
    public Page<Representatives> getEntities(Pageable pageable) {
        return repository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    public List<Representatives> findAll(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }
    public Page<Representatives> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return repository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    public List<Representatives> findByEmailStartsWith(String email) {
        return repository.findByEmailStartsWith(email);
    }
}
```

**This is my controller class:**

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rep")
public class RepController {
    protected final double pageSize = 10;
    @Autowired
    private RepService repService;

    @GetMapping("getRepresentativesStartingWith/{companyName}")
    ModelAndView getCompanyStartingWith(@PathVariable("companyName")
                                        String companyName) {
        return new ModelAndView("allRepresentatives :: representatives",
                "representatives",
                repService.findByEmailStartsWith(companyName));
    }
    @GetMapping("getFirstTenCompanies")
    public ModelAndView getFirstTenCompanies() {
        return getFirstTenEntities("allCompanies",
                "companies");
    }
    public ModelAndView getFirstTenEntities(String returnPage,
                                            String attributeName){
        var modelAndView = new ModelAndView(returnPage,
                "totalPages",
                (int) Math.ceil(repService.count()/pageSize));
        modelAndView.addObject(attributeName,
                repService.getEntities(0));//was 0
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping("getFirstTenRepresentatives")
    public ModelAndView getFirstTenReps(){
        return getFirstTenEntities("allRepresentatives",
                "representatives");
    }
    @GetMapping("getRepresentatives/{pageNum}")
    public ModelAndView getReps(@PathVariable("pageNum") Integer pageNum) {
        return new ModelAndView("allRepresentatives :: representatives",
                "representatives",
                repService.getEntities(pageNum));
    }

}
```

**This is the HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Aegis</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-BMbq2It2D3J17/C7aRklzOODG1IQ3+MHw3ifzBHMBwGO/0yUqYmsStgBjI0z5EYlaDEFnvYV7gNYdD3vFLRKsA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" integrity="sha512-BkpSL20WETFylMrcirBahHfSnY++H2O1W+UnEEO4yNIl+jI2+zowyoGJpbtk6bx97fBXf++WJHSSK2MV4ghPcg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <style>
        .bg-light {
            --bs-bg-opacity: 1;
            background-color: rgb(171, 28, 164, 1) !important;
        }

        h2{
            color: gray;
        }

        p{
            margin: 0;
        }

        body{
            font-family: 'Open Sans', "Segoe UI Light";
        }

        .form-headings{
            background-color: rgb(71 70 70);
        }

        .form-actions{
            background-color: darkgray;
        }

        .form-headings div{
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
        }

        i{
            font-size: x-large;
        }

        a{
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .dropdown-btn{
            background-color: #f0f8ff00;
            border:0;
            color: #212529;
            font-weight:400;
            padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 100%;
            display:block;
            text-align:start;
        }

        .dropdown-btn:hover{
            color: #1e2125;
            background-color: #e9ecef;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="m-5 ms-0 me-0 mb-4">
        ORGANISATIONS
    </h2>
    <div>

        <div class="row form-actions p-2 pe-0 ps-0" >
            <div class="col d-flex">

                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input id="search" class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Find Organisation" aria-label="Search">
                    <button id="search-button" class="btn btn-outline-light" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                </form>

            </div>

            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
                <div id="filters" class="dropdown me-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Filters
                    </button>
[redacted]
                </div>

                <div id="next-previous" class="d-flex">
                    <button id="previous" class="btn-secondary">< </button>
                    <span class="ps-2 pe-2 mt-auto mb-auto text-white" id="currentPage">1</span>
                    <span class="mt-auto mb-auto text-white" >/</span>
                    <span class="ps-2 pe-2 mt-auto mb-auto text-white" id="total-pages" th:text="${totalPages}"></span>
                    <button id="next" class="btn-secondary"> ></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
hiijojo
        <div id="entities" th:fragment="representatives">
            <table id="repsTable" class="display" data-order='[[1, "asc"]]'>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Company</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <div>
                    <tr th:each="rep : ${representatives}">
                        <td th:text="${rep.firstName}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${rep.lastName}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${rep.email}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${rep.gender}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${rep.company}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </div>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script th:src="@{/JS/script.js}"></script>
<script>
    let url = '/rep/getRepresentativesStartingWith/';
    let entityPageUrl = '/rep/getRepresentatives/';

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.filter').click(function(){
        $("#next, #previous").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#currentPage, #total-pages").empty();
        entityPageUrl = $(this).attr("data-url");
        replaceEntitiesWithData(entityPageUrl);
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        let table = $('#repsTable').DataTable({
            paging: false, // disable pagination
            searching: true, // enable searching
            ordering: true // enable ordering
        });
<!--        $('#repsTable').on('draw.dt', function(){-->
<!--        var table = $('#repsTable').DataTable();-->
        table.page.len(table.page.len()).draw('page'`)

    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Lastly, the JavaScript:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").keyup(function() {
        let searchInput = $("#search").val();
        replaceEntitiesWithData(url + searchInput);
        let controls = $("#next-previous");
        controls.addClass('d-flex');
        controls.show();
        $("#filters").hide();
    });
});


let currentPage =0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    let currentPageElement = $("#currentPage");
    let totalPages = parseInt($("#total-pages").text());

    if(totalPages ==1)
    $("#next, #previous").hide();

        $("#next").click(function (){
            currentPage++;

            setTextCurrentPageElement(currentPageElement, currentPage+1);

            if(currentPage >= totalPages-1) $(this).hide();

            replaceEntitiesWithData(entityPageUrl+currentPage);
        });

    $("#previous").click(function (){
    currentPage--;

    if(currentPage<0) currentPage=0;

    setTextCurrentPageElement(currentPageElement, currentPage+1);

    let nextControl = $("#next");

    if(nextControl.is(":hidden"))
    nextControl.show();

    replaceEntitiesWithData(entityPageUrl+currentPage);
    });
});

function setTextCurrentPageElement(element, value){
element.text(value);
}

function replaceEntitiesWithData(url){
$.get(url, function(data, status){
let entities = $("#entities");

entities.empty();
entities.append(data);

});
}
```

This is the HTML elements in the browser before clicking on any of the navigation buttons As you can see DataTables is enabled:

```
<div id="repsTable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer"><div id="repsTable_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label>Search:<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="repsTable"></label></div><table id="repsTable" class="display dataTable no-footer" data-order="[[1, &quot;asc&quot;]]" role="grid" aria-describedby="repsTable_info">
                <thead>
                <tr role="row"><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="repsTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="First Name: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 76.8594px;">First Name</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="repsTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Last Name: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 74.2188px;">Last Name</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="repsTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Email: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 189.75px;">Email</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="repsTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Gender: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 51.5469px;">Gender</th><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="repsTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Company: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 162.984px;" aria-sort="ascending">Company</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>                
                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                        <td>Thibaud</td>
                        <td class="">Isacoff</td>
                        <td>tisacoff0@toplist.cz</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">Cremin and Sons</td>
                    </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
                        <td>Juliane</td>
                        <td class="">Marchetti</td>
                        <td>jmarchetti1@si.edu</td>
                        <td>Female</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">Doyle and Sons</td>
                    </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
                        <td>Daren</td>
                        <td class="">Aldrich</td>
                        <td>daldrich2@jalbum.net</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">Emard Inc</td>
                    </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
                        <td>Barri</td>
                        <td class="">Raun</td>
                        <td>braun4@howstuffworks.com</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">Mills, Schimmel and Barrows</td>
                    </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
                        <td>Marcelo</td>
                        <td class="">Fishleigh</td>
                        <td>mfishleigh7@businessinsider.com</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">Nolan Inc</td>
                    </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
                        <td>Lewie</td>
                        <td class="">Demicoli</td>
                        <td>ldemicoli6@example.com</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">O'Kon-Upton</td>
                    </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
                        <td>Jacintha</td>
                        <td class="">Campana</td>
                        <td>jcampana3@state.gov</td>
                        <td>Female</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">Pfannerstill-Boyer</td>
                    </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
                        <td>Germana</td>
                        <td class="">Dyte</td>
                        <td>gdyte5@cnn.com</td>
                        <td>Female</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">Thiel, Frami and McClure</td>
                    </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
                        <td>Samuele</td>
                        <td class="">Dagnan</td>
                        <td>sdagnan9@mlb.com</td>
                        <td>Non-binary</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">Wuckert and Sons</td>
                    </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
                        <td>Caterina</td>
                        <td class="">Vallens</td>
                        <td>cvallens8@google.com.br</td>
                        <td>Female</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">Zieme-Stoltenberg</td>
                    </tr></tbody>
            </table><div class="dataTables_info" id="repsTable_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 10 of 10 entries</div></div>
```

**And this is after: As you can see DataTables is no longer enabled**

```
<div id="entities"><div id="entities">
            <div>
                    </div><table id="repsTable" class="display" data-order="[[1, &quot;asc&quot;]]">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Company</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td>Had</td>
                        <td>Cantos</td>
                        <td>hcantosa@over-blog.com</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                        <td>Gusikowski-Halvorson</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Alyosha</td>
                        <td>Scurrell</td>
                        <td>ascurrellb@dyndns.org</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                        <td>Lehner and Sons</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Galven</td>
                        <td>Behrendsen</td>
                        <td>gbehrendsenc@newsvine.com</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                        <td>Marquardt, Heathcote and Powlowski</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Julita</td>
                        <td>Dunsford</td>
                        <td>jdunsfordd@printfriendly.com</td>
                        <td>Bigender</td>
                        <td>Vandervort-O'Conner</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Irene</td>
                        <td>Prestie</td>
                        <td>iprestiee@howstuffworks.com</td>
                        <td>Female</td>
                        <td>Braun, Jaskolski and Ratke</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Marlee</td>
                        <td>Tutt</td>
                        <td>mtuttf@ca.gov</td>
                        <td>Female</td>
                        <td>Schmeler LLC</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Vasili</td>
                        <td>Boutellier</td>
                        <td>vboutellierg@statcounter.com</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                        <td>Rutherford and Sons</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Monika</td>
                        <td>Papworth</td>
                        <td>mpapworthh@imageshack.us</td>
                        <td>Female</td>
                        <td>Jerde Inc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Claire</td>
                        <td>Leftridge</td>
                        <td>cleftridgei@aol.com</td>
                        <td>Female</td>
                        <td>Gislason and Sons</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cyndia</td>
                        <td>Prandin</td>
                        <td>cprandinj@house.gov</td>
                        <td>Female</td>
                        <td>Sporer-Schimmel</td>
                    </tr>
                
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div></div>
```

How can I keep DataTables enabled while navigating between pages? If anymore information is needed please let me know.